# Weird nested dict

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to get access to a nested dict, the problem is each obj in the dict has a different number has a key, and the same goes for the one inside it, here is the json source:

```
{
    "100": {
        "status": {
            "timestamp": "2020-10-12T23:24:26.146Z",
            "error_code": 0,
            "error_message": null,
            "elapsed": 19,
            "credit_count": 1,
            "notice": null
        },
        "data": {
            "100": {
                "id": 100,
                "name": "Particle",
                "symbol": "PRT",
                "category": "coin",
                "description": "/`enter code here`",
                "slug": "particle",
                "logo": "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/100.png",
                "subreddit": "",
                "notice": "",
                "tags": ["mineable"],
                "tag-names": ["Mineable"],
                "tag-groups": ["OTHER"],
                "urls": {
                    "website": ["http://www.bitparticle.com/"],
                    "twitter": [],
                    "message_board": [],
                    "chat": [],
                    "explorer": ["http://chaincollider.bitparticle.com/chain/Particle/"],
                    "reddit": [],
                    "technical_doc": [],
                    "source_code": [],
                    "announcement": []
                },
                "platform": null,
                "date_added": "2014-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
                "twitter_username": "",
                "is_hidden": 0
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to get access to the symbol and the logo, I managed to do so only for 1 obj by typing

```
json_file['100']['data']['100']['symbol']
```

My final goal is to have a complete list with the logo and symbol of each obj.

Comment: If you want a list with all the values anyway, loop over the keys: `for k1 in json_file: for k2 in json_file[k1]['data']: x = json_file[k1]['data'][k2]['symbol'] ...`

Comment: It works, it feel so good! thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop over the keys in the dictionary and then access the values behind those keys:

```
for k1 in json_file:
    for k2 in json_file[k1]["data"]:
        symbol = json_file[k1]["data"][k2]["symbol"]
        ...
```

If you just want a list of all symbols, you could also use a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> [json_file[k1]["data"][k2]["symbol"] for k1 in json_file for k2 in json_file[k1]["data"]]
['PRT']
```